# How should a string be matched with a regular expression in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm finding it hard to match strings using NSRegularExpression.  Generic alpha characters are not a problem with [a-z] but if I need to match a word like 'import' I'm struggling to make it work.  I'm sure I have to escape the word in some manner but I can't find any docs around this.  A really basic example would be

```
{{import "hello"}}
```

where I want to get hold of the string: hello

edit: to clarify - 'hello' could be any string - it's the bit I want returned

Comment: Shouldn't `NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:@"hello"];` suffice?

Comment: `[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"{{import \"Hello\"}}" options:0 error:&err]`...?

Comment: I have clarified with an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression matches the text between the "-s in your example:

```
\{\{import "([^"]+)"\}\}
```

The match will be stored in the first match group.

Comment: ok - sorry - I understand now what you mean by first match group and you are correct: NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1]; rather than NSRange matchRange = [match range]